# How to align the equation

Tags: align

I am having the following code for the equation. I want to align the equation w.r.t =.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
          a4paper,
          total={170 mm,257 mm},
          left=20 mm,
          top=20 mm,
         }
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    N = (1\times2^{5})\; \textbf{+}\; (0\times2^{4})\; \textbf{+}\; (1\times2^{3})\; \textbf{+}\; (1\times2^{2})\; \textbf{+}\; (0\times2^{1})\; \textbf{+}\; (1\times2^{0}) \\
    \textbf{+}\; (1\times2^{-1})\; \textbf{+}\; (0\times2^{-2})\; \textbf{+}\; (1\times2^{-3})\; \textbf{+}\; (1\times2^{-4}) \\
    = 32\; \textbf{+}\; 8\; \textbf{+}\; 4\; \textbf{+}\; 1\; \textbf{+}\; 0.5\; \textbf{+}\; 0.125\; \textbf{+}\; 0.0625 \\
    = 45.6875
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

With the above code, I am getting the output as follows:

[image: Obtained output]

I want the output as follows:

[image: Desired output]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Why all the `\textbf{+}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of versions. The first one aligns the first long term on the right-hand side on the right margin as in you picture; the second version is a possible alternative (de gustibus).

Assuming that you really want bold `+`, `\textbf{+}` is a very bad way to do it. At the very least, it completely ruins spacing, as you probably have noticed since you had to put a lot of `\;` manually. The package `bm` does a better job at making bold math *and* at the same time keeping the correct spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{align*}
N &= 
\begin{aligned}[t]
(1\times2^{5}) + (0\times2^{4}) + (1\times2^{3}) + (1\times2^{2}) + (0\times2^{1}) + (1\times2^{0}) \\
    {}+ (1\times2^{-1}) + (0\times2^{-2}) + (1\times2^{-3}) + (1\times2^{-4})
\end{aligned}
\\
&= 32 + 8 + 4 + 1 + 0.5 + 0.125 + 0.0625 \\
&= 45.6875
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
N &= 
\begin{aligned}[t]
&(1\times2^{5}) + (0\times2^{4}) + (1\times2^{3}) + (1\times2^{2}) + (0\times2^{1}) + (1\times2^{0}) \\
    &+ (1\times2^{-1}) + (0\times2^{-2}) + (1\times2^{-3}) + (1\times2^{-4})
\end{aligned}
\\
&= 32 + 8 + 4 + 1 + 0.5 + 0.125 + 0.0625 \\
&= 45.6875
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
N &= 
\begin{aligned}[t]
(1\times2^{5}) \bm{+} (0\times2^{4}) \bm{+} (1\times2^{3}) \bm{+} (1\times2^{2}) \bm{+} (0\times2^{1}) \bm{+} (1\times2^{0}) \\
    {}\bm{+} (1\times2^{-1}) \bm{+} (0\times2^{-2}) \bm{+} (1\times2^{-3}) \bm{+} (1\times2^{-4})
\end{aligned}
\\
&= 32 \bm{+} 8 \bm{+} 4 \bm{+} 1 \bm{+} 0.5 \bm{+} 0.125 \bm{+} 0.0625 \\
&= 45.6875
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]